# expiration object s3 through php sdk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I want to set an expiration date for an object on s3 I create the object like this:

```
$this->s3->putObject(array(
'Bucket' => BUCKET,
'Key'=> "path",
'SourceFile'   => $fileTmp,
'Expires' => time()+2*60,
'ACL'    => 'private'
));
```

But when I check file on aws S3 Console the object keeps:

```
Expiry Date:    None
Expiration Rule:    N/A
```

How can I set object expiration?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `putBucketLifecycle` method like that:

```
    $result = $client->putBucketLifecycleConfiguration([
        'Bucket' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
        'LifecycleConfiguration' => [
            'Rules' => [ // REQUIRED
                [
                    'Expiration' => [
                        'Date' => <integer || string || DateTime>,
                        'Days' => <integer>,
                        'ExpiredObjectDeleteMarker' => true || false,
                    ],
                    'ID' => '<string>',
                    'Prefix' => '<string>',
                    'Status' => 'Enabled|Disabled', // REQUIRED
                ],
                // ...
            ],
],
]);
```

**Note**

1. This method will replace all the existing rules. So if you need
   to append a new rule I recommend you to use
   `getBucketLifecycleConfiguration` before and merge the previous
   rules with the new one.
2. You can only set a Lifecycle rule on a prefix (or tag), not an object.
3. 'prefix' is your path, excluding the file name, with a trailing slash.

**Resources**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putbucketlifecycleconfiguration

Answer (score 1):

Lifecycle policies are set per bucket, not per file.

Here's how to set a Lifecycle policy for a bucket:

1. In AWS S3 console (the web version), **click** on the bucket
2. Choose **Properties**; expand **Lifecycle**
3. *Add Rule* appears. Click it.
4. Complete the wizard using your own set of rules

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with the php sdk?

Comment: I don't know, but if the API supports it, then the SDK supports it as well.

Comment: The question mentioned php sdk. Your answer is about the console. Check my answer to do the same with php sdk